# Can a UserControl hide itself via its own XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, user-controls

If I have a user control that I want to act as an overlay, I would like to it hide itself, so to speak, when it is not needed.  It will know this by via a dependency property it has that the parent object can bind to.  My first thought would be to do this via the out most grid of the UC.  So Something like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:valueConverters="clr-namespace:Some.Namespace;assembly=Some.Assembly">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <valueConverters:VisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl, Mode=FindAncestor}}"
          Visibility="{Binding ShowMyself, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">>
        .................
        .................
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This works fine.  Now if I want to hide the control via the Parent object, that is easy enough with something like this:

```
<controls:MyUserControl ShowMyself="{Binding ShowUserControl">
    .........
    .........
</controls:MyUserControl>
```

But I was wondering if it would be possible do do something like this so the control, essentially, hides itself:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:valueConverters="clr-namespace:Some.Namespace;assembly=Some.Assembly">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <valueConverters:VisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <UserControl.Visibility>
        <Binding Path="ShowMyself" Converter="{StaticResource VisibilityConverter}"/>
    </UserControl.Visibility>

    <Grid>
        .................
        .................
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I realize there is probably little to no difference in practical terms and this may be purely academic but it would seem more "appropriate".  If I try the second scenario the problem becomes the Binding is outside the DataContext and cannot seen the property - the DataContext is now that of the parent object which makes sense since the UserControl tags themselves essentially contain no "meat".

Is it just not possible?

Comment: anything is possible if you follow MVVM

Comment: NETscape, this control is essentially pure UI to be used in other UCs (that do use MVVM).  So I am not sure MVVM applies to this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want bind to a property of `UserControl` on `Usercontrol` level use [`RelativeSource.Self`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.self(v=vs.110).aspx) as binding source

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <valueConverters:VisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.Visibility>
        <Binding 
            RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" 
            Path="ShowMyself" 
            Converter="{StaticResource VisibilityConverter}"/>
    </UserControl.Visibility>
    <!-- .... -->
</UserControl>
```

**It needs to be done in that order** to avoid problems with accessing local `VisibilityConverter` resource

Comment: Thank dkozl.  I tried everything EXCEPT the RelativeSource to self in the binding for the <UserControl.Visibility> tag!  It gets me the right datacontext.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a [`RelativeSource Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyUserControl"
...
    Visibility="{Binding ShowMyself, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type YourPrefix:MyUserControl}}, Converter="{StaticResource 
    VisibilityConverter}">
    ...
</UserControl>
```

Comment: To reduce the amount of XAML, can't you use `RelativeSource=Self` as a shortcut in the binding?

Comment: Sheridan, I tried this.  The problem is the StaticResource - how can the binding access it if it is declared in the UC below it?

Comment: Declare it in your `Application.Resources` section in `App.xaml` and then it will be available application wide.